# Get all parent categories Django - Follow foreign key UP

Tags: django, foreign-key-relationship, categories, django-select-related, django-related-manager

I got the following models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("self", blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("category")
        verbose_name_plural = _("categories")

     def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name


class Item(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_("name"))
     keywords = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_("keywords"))
     category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

     class Meta:
         abstract = True
         verbose_name = _('item')
         verbose_name_plural = _('items')


class Product(Item):
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8, verbose_name=_("price"))
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, verbose_name=_("brand"))
    article_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name=_("article_number"))

    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('product')
        verbose_name_plural = _('products')
```

Let's say i have the following categories in the database:

```
ID     NAME      PARENT_ID
1      Products       null
2      Phones            1
3      iPhones           2
```

I can get the top category by doing the following:

```
#This is a product with the category "iPhones"
product.category.parent.parent
```

But that's not nice because a product can be x numbers of categories deep.

How can I get all the related categories in an array or something?

```
Wanted output = [iPhones, Phones, Products]
```

Comment: I think you should have `ManyToMany` with `Item` and `Category`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a Model Property Method for the item class:

```
  class Item(models.Model):
     @property
     def all_categories(self):
        categories = []
        current_category = self.category
        while current_category is not None:
            categories.append(current_category)
            current_category = current_category.parent
        return categories
        #optional return reversed list:
        #return list(reversed(categories))
```

Now you can get the desired list with

```
product.all_categories
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I managed to come up with a solution myself, but I will switch to your code right away :)

Heres my solution.

`def get_all_categories(self, cat_obj):

        category_list = []

        if cat_obj.parent_id:
            c = cat_obj.parent
            category_list.append(c)
            more = self.get_all_categories(c)
            category_list.extend(more)

        if cat_obj == self and category_list:
            category_list.reverse()
            category_list.append(self)
        return category_list`